# Redirect generic page to specific

Tags: .htaccess

Im trying to redirect any page that starts with the directory blog to a specific page.
Here is what I what to do:

```
test.com/blog/ => test.com/news/
test.com/blog/anything => test.com/news/
```

Its working well with the root blog/, but it does work well for the articles.
What should I do?

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 ^/blog/?$ https://test.com/news$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RewriteEngine` and `Redirect` are directives from 2 different module. Don't mix up those. Moreover you don't need `$` in target as regular expression is only used for matching a pattern.

You can use following rule **inside the `/blog/.htaccess`** file:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^ /news/ [L,R=301]
```

This will redirect any request that starts with `/blog/` to `/news/`.